# How do we check octet rule in resonance structures?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

For example, this carbon has an incomplete octet:

[image]

Can we say this is because C has configuration $\mathrm{1s^2 2s^2 2p^2}$ and hence here its just forming 3 bonds whereas it should form 4 to make it $\mathrm{2p^6}$ and complete its octet? Or do we say that it's forming 3 bonds and hence has 6 electrons and therefore it's octet isn't complete?

Comment: Even though this structure "exists" on paper or computer screen, it is meaningless in the real world. In other words, this structure does not exist in the real world as drawn and has only come into existence as part of the human effort to describe the chemistry of this world using simple and straightforward symbolism. As you probably know, the true structure is a hybrid of all resonance structures, and the octet rule is satisfied for the central carbon. Therefore, I think this question has no actual answer.

Comment: Ok I agree with that. But my main concern is that how do we see the octet rule in atoms? Like I just want you explain this with respect to this particular structure. If you want I can present another example. I'm actually very confused how to check the octet rule in structures like these.

Comment: Like how can we say the octet isn't complete? By seeing the configuration and seeing the vacancy available or check how many bonds and lone pair an atom has? What're we supposed to do normally?

Comment: The octet rule is a measure that helps you to draw a correct and plausible Lewis structure. The rules for drawing correct Lewis structure are found in every basic chemistry book and should be followed in order. See section 5 in this [link](http://www.chem.ucla.edu/~harding/lewisdots.html):  *If the octets are incomplete, and more electrons remain to be shared, move one electron per bond per atom to make another bond...* - **if the octets are incomplete** - if you follow the rules in sequence, you should not be left with an incomplete octet for carbon.

Comment: Also, traditionally, when you move (again, on paper...) the electrons from the double bond to the carbonyl oxygen, you should simultaneously move another pair of non-bonding electrons from the other oxygen **in order to complete carbon's octet**. Even on paper, you should never leave carbon with less than 4 bonds if they can be formed. This 3-bonded, positively-charged carbon is merely a methodological transition state for education purposes. Octet rule does not really apply in these circumstances.

Comment: Once you know the carbon involved, aren't the two assertions the same?

Comment: Then how do we say that an oxygen adjacent to carbon with a positive charge is highly stable if it's octet is complete and highly unstable if it's octet isn't while drawing the resonance structures?

Comment: I guess we could say that the farther you are from an octet, the more unstable you are. But again, all these drawing methods and resonance structures are for illustrative purposes. I don't think you could expect the octet rule (or any other rule, for that matter) to apply for a chemical structure that does not actually exist. The structure above does not float around in a stable manner. It does not exist independently...

Comment: Ok and just for educational purposes if we've an oxygen forming 3 bonds and having a lone pair with a positive charge and another again with a positive charge forming 1 bond and having 2 lone pairs which one will be considered closest to the octet rule and why? Can I say first because it will have 8 electrons and second will have 6? Just for the purpose of solving questions with ease.

Comment: Because if we go with the traditional way of 2p4 and it gaining just two electrons more then I think octet will be violated right? Or can I go with this way too and for the oxygen forming 3 bonds with a positive charge I can say that the valence configuration will be 2p3 and 3 bonds will form satisfying it's octet and the 2s2 electrons which don't participate will be shown as lone pair? Which approach is better according to you?

Comment: Octet rule means 8 electrons around an atom, doesn't matter if bonding or non-bonding. If an atom doesn't have 8 electrons around it, it violates the octet rule (but that does not always mean that you made a mistake; there are cases where the octet rule is not satisfied, for various reasons: expanded valence shells, hydrogen requiring only two electrons etc.)